# Match three columns on two worksheet and copying like rows on both sheets to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim rOriginal As Range          'row records in the lookup sheet (cList = Sheet2)
Dim rFind As Range              'row record in the target sheet (TotalList = Sheet1)
Dim rTableOriginal As Range     'row records in the lookup sheet (cList = Sheet2)
Dim rTableFind As Range         'row record in the target sheet (TotalList = Sheet1)
Dim shOriginal As Worksheet
Dim shFind As Worksheet
Dim booFound As Boolean
Dim shMix As Worksheet

'Initiate all used objects and variables
Set shOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Male")
Set shFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Female")
Set shMix = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mix")
Set rTableOriginal = shOriginal.Range(shOriginal.Rows(2), shOriginal.Rows(shOriginal.Rows.count).End(xlUp))
Set rTableFind = shFind.Range(shFind.Rows(2), shFind.Rows(shFind.Rows.count).End(xlUp))
booFound = False

      For Each rOriginal In rTableOriginal.Rows
       booFound = False
         For Each rFind In rTableFind.Rows
           'Check if the E and F column contain the same information
               If rOriginal.Cells(1, 1) = rFind.Cells(1, 1) And rOriginal.Cells(1, 13) = rFind.Cells(1, 13) And rOriginal.Cells(1, 11) = rFind.Cells(1, 11) Then
                 'The record is found so we can search for the next one
                    booFound = True
                    GoTo FindNextOriginal 'Alternatively use Exit For
               End If
         Next rFind

            'In case the code is extended I always use a boolean and an If statement to make sure we cannot
            'by accident end up in this copy-paste-apply_yellow part!!
            If booFound = True Then
                'If not found then copy form the Original sheet ...
                rOriginal.Copy
                rFind.Copy
                '... paste on the Find sheet and apply the Yellow interior color
                With shMix.Rows(Mix.Rows.count + 1)
                    .PasteSpecial

                End With

            End If

FindNextOriginal:
        Next rOriginal
```

So I have searched the site and came up with the codes above. But it still doesn't seem to work. My objective is to match 3 columns on sheet "Male" with another 3 columns on sheet "Female" if it matches, the code will then copy the row on both sheets and paste it on sheet "Mix". The columns I am trying to compare are columns A , K and M respectively.

Example:

```
Column A | Column K | Column M
1/1/2000 | 20       | 1 
2/1/2000 | 21       | 4 
3/1/2000 | 22       | 5 

1/1/2000 | 20       | 1 
4/1/2000 | 24       | 3 
6/1/2000 | 25       | 6
```

Copy row 1 on both worksheet and paste it in sheet "Mix"

Comment: Will the matching data always be on the same row in both sheets?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the most efficient method for something like a three column match is often a Scripting.Dictionary object that comes with its own unique reference key index. Temporary 'helper' columns that concatenate the three values for a single comparison are another option but 'in-memory' evaluation is usually the most efficient.

```
Sub three_col_match_and_copy()
    Dim c As Long, v As Long, w As Long, vTMPs As Variant, itm As String, vVALs() As Variant, k As Variant
    Dim dTMPs As Object '<~~ late binding use As New Scipting.Dictionary for early binding
    Dim dMIXs As Object '<~~ late binding use As New Scipting.Dictionary for early binding

    'late binding of the dictionary object
    Set dTMPs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dMIXs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'grab all of Males into variant array
    With Worksheets("male")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                vTMPs = .Cells.Value2
            End With
        End With
    End With

    'build first dictionary
    For v = LBound(vTMPs, 1) To UBound(vTMPs, 1)
        If Not dTMPs.exists(Join(Array(vTMPs(v, 1), vTMPs(v, 11), vTMPs(v, 13)), ChrW(8203))) Then
            itm = "gonna be discarded in any event"
            dTMPs.Add Key:=Join(Array(vTMPs(v, 1), vTMPs(v, 11), vTMPs(v, 13)), ChrW(8203)), _
                      Item:=itm
        End If
    Next v

    'grab all of Females into reused variant array
    With Worksheets("female")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                vTMPs = .Cells.Value2
            End With
        End With
    End With

    'save for later
    c = UBound(vTMPs, 2)

    'build second dictionary on matches
    For v = LBound(vTMPs, 1) To UBound(vTMPs, 1)
        If dTMPs.exists(Join(Array(vTMPs(v, 1), vTMPs(v, 11), vTMPs(v, 13)), ChrW(8203))) Then
            itm = vTMPs(v, 1)
            For w = LBound(vTMPs, 2) + 1 To UBound(vTMPs, 2)
                itm = Join(Array(itm, vTMPs(v, w)), ChrW(8203))
            Next w
            dMIXs.Add Key:=Join(Array(vTMPs(v, 1), vTMPs(v, 11), vTMPs(v, 13)), ChrW(8203)), _
                      Item:=itm
        End If
    Next v

    'continue if there is something to xfer
    If CBool(dMIXs.Count) Then
        'create variant array of the matches from the dictionary
        v = 1
        ReDim vVALs(1 To dMIXs.Count, 1 To UBound(vTMPs, 2))
        Debug.Print LBound(vVALs, 1) & ":" & UBound(vVALs, 1)
        Debug.Print LBound(vVALs, 2) & ":" & UBound(vVALs, 2)
        For Each k In dMIXs
            vTMPs = Split(dMIXs.Item(k), ChrW(8203))
            For w = LBound(vTMPs) To UBound(vTMPs)
                vVALs(v, w + 1) = vTMPs(w)
            Next w
            v = v + 1
            Debug.Print dMIXs.Item(k)
        Next k

        'put the matched rows into the Mix worksheet
        With Worksheets("mix")
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                With .Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), UBound(vVALs, 2)).Offset(1, 0)
                    .Cells = vVALs
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End If


    dTMPs.RemoveAll: Set dTMPs = Nothing
    dMIXs.RemoveAll: Set dMIXs = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have used raw values in the transfer. You will most likely have to correctly format things like date values in the **Mix** worksheet but that should not be a problem for a 'programming enthusiast'.

Comment: Got a type mismatch error on line : itm = Join(Array(itm, vTMPs(v, w)), ChrW(8203))

Comment: If I had the data in front of me, I would look at that row to see what was causing the error. fwiw, it works fine on my sample data expanded from your limited samples data.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the following code

```
 Sub Test()

Dim lastr As Long
Dim lastrmale As Long
Dim lastrfemale As Long
Dim lastrmix As Long
Dim malesheet As Worksheet
Dim Femalesheet As Worksheet
Dim mixsheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set malesheet = Worksheets("Male")
Set Femalesheet = Worksheets("Female")
Set mixsheet = Worksheets("mix")
lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A" & malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastrfemale = Femalesheet.Range("A" & Femalesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastr = WorksheetFunction.Min(lastrmale, lastrfemale)
lastrmix = 2
For i = 2 To lastr

    If (malesheet.Range("A" & i).Value = Femalesheet.Range("A" & i).Value) And (malesheet.Range("K" & i).Value = Femalesheet.Range("K" & i).Value) And (malesheet.Range("M" & i).Value = Femalesheet.Range("M" & i).Value) Then

        malesheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
        mixsheet.Range("A" & lastrmix).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    lastrmix = lastrmix + 1
    Femalesheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
        mixsheet.Range("A" & lastrmix).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    lastrmix = lastrmix + 1

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: it says error range of object worksheet  failed on line : lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A" & malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row